# Proxy issue when running SQL Server job for Visual Studio (.exe file)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, proxy

I have a VS project that fetches data from

```
// ... some code ...

using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{               
    webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + credentials;
    var json = webClient.DownloadString("https://........."");

    List<Example> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Example>>(json);

    // .... some more code ....
}
```

Everything works fine when I run the package from within VS, with the exception of 1 or 2 times when I got an error

> The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authorization required

The SQL Server error is this:

> Unhandled exception.System.Net.WebException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
>
> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
>
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
>
> at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)     at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SendRequest()
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
> at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
> at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits(WebRequest request, Stream writeStream)
> at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
> at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
> at .....
>
> The step failed.

Can it be that I need to disable proxy within my VS project before I run the query, or can it be something else?

Any help would be grateful

Comment: I removed the SQL Server and tsql tags.  This error isn't coming from SQL Server, it's coming from .NET.

Comment: It doesn't appear you are using a proxy from the code above. But it's really unclear: how does SQL Server come into this? How are you running this code? Is it an SQLCLR procedure, or is it triggered from Powershell, something else? Are you even running this on the same machine as when you run it in the VS debugger?

Comment: You need to provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here. In fact, I can't reproduce your problem, so it's hard to fix.